# Creating vm instance on azure through shell or ansible?

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-vm-scale-set

I want to create a VM instance on azure through ansible/shell script from my machine.

**ways i have found**

1. Installing **az cli** on my machine, **az login** and create instance.

**Problem  with az cli** :In this way i can create instance but i need a session login for infinite time unless i logout. If i logout or system logs me out then i have to login manually with portal to cli which i don't want.If there is any automate process to login with keys or passwords.

can anyone suggesst me how can i acheive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use the service principal to login both for the Azure CLI and ansible. In this way, it works as the username and password so that you need not log in with portal.

You can follow [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) via the Azure CLI command to create the service principal and use it to log in. And the ansible steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ansible-install-configure?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fansible%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#create-azure-credentials).

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the login session time in this case.

Comment: @DhirajKumar You just need the command `az login --service-principal -u appId -p secret` for Azure CLI login in the script. The ansible just needs the credentials file.

Comment: I got your point. But my concern is for how long session will continue if i have logged  in.

Comment: @DhirajKumar As I know, the session will continue the whole script time.

Comment: Yes but will session long for a  month ,year or days ?

Comment: @DhirajKumar No, if you just use a script, it can only continue the script time.

Comment: but i am not still clear if i do az login then for how long this will continue ?

Comment: @DhirajKumar It will continue to untile the script is over or you log in again in the script.